# Insert, Delete or Update cannot be performed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

**My query seems to be correct but why is this happening?**

[image]

```
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Sparrow vivek\Documents\Billing.accdb";
        con.Open();
        DateTime a = Convert.ToDateTime(label2.Text);
        String query = "INSERT INTO balancesheet (BillNumber,CusName,Date,Amount) values (?,?,?,?)";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",label3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", label4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", a.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", label6.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: `[Date]` as its probably reserved

Comment: Are the types right? If you send `Text` it will be a `String`. Is that the correct type? Also, make sure you include the full error text here and not just in a picture.

Comment: is there an inner exception?

Comment: to be honest with you... it was working with Mysql... but not for access why?

Comment: See if you can capture the executed SQL (with the Profiler), that will show you where the syntax error is

Comment: i am sorry i don't understand please...

Comment: @BerndLinde Profiler like Sql Server Profiler? Not a chance to have it in Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query contains a [reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266): Date. To use it you need to use square brackets around that name

```
String query = "INSERT INTO balancesheet (BillNumber,CusName,[Date],Amount) values (?,?,?,?)";
```

It is highly recommended to avoid these names. If it is still possible change that name ASAP.

Now let's examine that list of AddWithValue. In this method the datatype of the parameter is automatically determined by the value that you pass. You have every value passed to the parameter collection of type string. But it is probable that your database fields  doesn't want a string as value. For example Date,Amount seems requires a datetime and a number

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",label3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", label4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", a); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(label6.Text));
```

Comment: @Sparrowvivek can you give more details? is it the same error? is there more information in the thrown exception? is your db functional? can you write the query in another sql editor?

Comment: The SYNTAX ERROR is surely caused by that, now you have a different error right?

Comment: no steve same error, so weird right? yes Default i've tried it with Mysql and it works fine...

Comment: At this point the syntax is correct. What are the datatype of the table fields? Try also to use VS BUILD menu to _Clean Solution_ and _Rebuild Solution_