# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement with parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i am getting this error so often, i can't find out what's wrong in here?

[image: Error]

```
con.Open();

String query = "INSERT INTO user (username,[password]) values(a,b)";
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("a",textBox1.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", textBox2.Text);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("User Account Created");
this.Close();
```

Comment: did bro not working either...

Comment: Um, your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489119/insert-delete-or-update-cannot-be-performed) seems to be answered. But here, you don't even have the same synatx (missing `?` and replaces with letters)

Comment: i was trying all the possibilities... first ? wasn't working then i switched to letter it did so weird...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should start with `@` like `@Name`. try this:

```
con.Open();
String query = "INSERT INTO user (Username, [Password]) values(@Username, @Password)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("User Account Created");
this.Close();
```

Read [Using Variables and Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212846%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)